# Fetch data fail with getx, what is wrong method?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I've done implement service with getx controller but why data from internet can't display, i wanna show all item , i have 2 method for get data from internet, case 1 i write get method for general, and case 2 i write to specific method, let's check my code below, what is wrong with my method i feel it's not wrong code like normally, but why value return null

> base_client.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'app_exception.dart';

class BaseClient {
  static const TIME_OUT_DURATION = Duration(seconds: 10);
  //* GET
  Future<dynamic> get({required String baseUrl, required String api}) async {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(baseUrl + api);
    try {
      http.Response response = await http.get(uri);
      print(response);
      return _processResponse(response);
    } on SocketException {
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  dynamic _processResponse(http.Response response) {
    if (kDebugMode) {
      log('${response.request!.url} ${response.request?.method}');
      log('${response.statusCode} : ${response.body}');
    }
    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case 200:
      case 201:
        var responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
        return responseJson;
      case 400:
        throw BadRequestException(
            utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes), response.request!.url.toString());
      case 401:
      case 404:
        throw UnAuthorizedException(
            utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes), response.request!.url.toString());
      case 500:
      case 502:
      // throw ApiNotRespondingException(
      //     utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes), response.request!.url.toString());
      default:
        throw FetchDataException(
            'Error occured with code : ${response.statusCode}',
            response.request!.url.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

> home_controller.dart

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:resto_app/app/models/resto_list.dart';
import 'package:resto_app/shared/constant/api_services.dart';
import 'package:resto_app/shared/services/base_client.dart';

class HomeController extends GetxController {
  //TODO: Implement HomeController

  Rx<RestoList> allProduct = RestoList(count: 0, restaurants: []).obs;
  RxBool isLoadingAllProduct = false.obs;
  Future<void> getAllProduct({bool usingIsFalse = true}) async {
    if (usingIsFalse) {
      isLoadingAllProduct.value = true;
    }
    var result = await BaseClient()
        .get(baseUrl: ApiService.baseURL, api: ApiService.allResto);
    if (result != null) {
      allProduct.value = RestoList.fromJson(result);
    }
    isLoadingAllProduct.value = false;
  }
}
```

> home_view.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:get/get.dart';

import '../controllers/home_controller.dart';

class HomeView extends StatelessWidget {
  final HomeController _homeController = Get.put(HomeController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(() => Scaffold(
            body: Center(
          child: Text(
              _homeController.allProduct.value.restaurants.length.toString()),
        )));
  }
}
```

> api_service.dart

```
class ApiService {
  static const baseURL = 'https://restaurant-api.dicoding.dev';
  static const allResto = '/list';
  static const detailPage = '/detail/';
  static const searchResto = '/search?q=fnfn8mytkpmkfw1e867';
}
```

> app_exception.dart

```
class AppException implements Exception {
  final String? message;
  final String? prefix;
  final String? url;
  AppException({this.message, this.prefix, this.url});
}

class BadRequestException extends AppException {
  BadRequestException(String message, String url)
      : super(message: message, prefix: 'Bad Request', url: url);
}

class FetchDataException extends AppException {
  FetchDataException(String message, String url)
      : super(message: message, prefix: 'Unable to process', url: url);
}

class FetchDataException2 extends AppException {
  FetchDataException2(String message, String url)
      : super(message: message, prefix: 'Unable to process data', url: url);
}

class ApiNotRespondingException extends AppException {
  ApiNotRespondingException(String message, String url)
      : super(message: message, prefix: 'Api not responded in time', url: url);
}

class UnAuthorizedException extends AppException {
  UnAuthorizedException(String message, String url)
      : super(message: message, prefix: 'UnAuthorized Request', url: url);
}
```

I think it's work at normally, but still value null to result

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

- firstly add function in class **HomeController** :

  ```
  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    getAllProduct();
  }
  ```
- secondly replace existing code with this code in class **HomeView** :

  ```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    import 'package:get/get.dart';

    import '../controllers/home_controller.dart';

    class HomeView extends GetView<HomeController> {   // replace Stateless with GetView 
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Obx(() => Scaffold(
                body: Center(
              child: Text(
               controller.allProduct.value.restaurants.length.toString()),
            )));
      }
    }
  ```